# Unity 2D Objects on different layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So.. I generated a random map and some objects in Unity..
But like in the real gameplay they are put in different layers as in the picture below.

Is there any way I can make them on the same layer?
If my codes are needed please let me know, I'll put them on.

[image: Picture1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `RectTransform.position.z` of all elements to same value (for example 0).

```
    RectTransform.position = new Vector3(RectTransfarm.position.x, RectTransform.position.y, 0.0f);
```

You can also do this when creating an object. Post your code where you are creating  objects for getting example.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a orthographic camera and the different layers should not matter or follow Nikita's solution and set the Z position to 0 when instantiating object.